# Porque el cambio de tema con Provider hace rebuild 2 veces de los widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, state

Tengo una app la cual maneja Provider, he implementado un boton para cambiar de tema, pero en las screens, parece ser que pasa por el build 2 veces cuando cambio de tema, es esto normal? no deberia renderizar solo 1 vez con el nuevo tema?

dejo el codgigo por aqui:

```
class ChangeThemeButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChangeThemeButtonWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeProvider themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
    const IconData lightIcon = Icons.wb_sunny;
    const IconData darkIcon = Icons.brightness_2_outlined;
    IconData icon = themeProvider.isDarkMode ? lightIcon : darkIcon;

    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (icon == darkIcon) {
          icon = lightIcon;
          themeProvider.isDarkMode = true;
        } else {
          icon = darkIcon;
           themeProvider.isDarkMode = false;
        }
      },
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(
            icon,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
           Text(
                    "appbar.contraste",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelSmall,
                  ).tr(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Y la clase provider que se inyecta para los cambios de tema
**Theme provider:**

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.light;

  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  set isDarkMode(bool isOn) {
    themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Tengo un theme provider en el main escuchando ya que sin este no cambia de tema la aplicación:

```
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ThemeProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ConfigurationFormProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => HomeScreenProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AutoposProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => LanguageProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ImportesProvider()),
      ],
      builder: ((context, _) {
        final ThemeProvider themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: true);

        return MaterialApp(
          locale: context.locale,
          supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
          localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          routes: AppRoutes.getAppRoutes(),
          initialRoute: AppRoutes.getInitialScreen(configurationModel),
          onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.onGenerateRoute,
          theme: AutoposTheme.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: AutoposTheme.darkTheme,
          themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
        );
      }),
    );
```

si se fijan esta todo el false menos el del main que es el que necesito para refrescar la app, ya que si ese lo pongo a false obviamente no hace nada.

Comment: donde está el ThemeProvider ?

Comment: tnego un theme provider en el main <-- he actualizado post

Comment: podría ser que un build es por el cambio del valor del provider y otra build es que el materialapp al reconstruir el tema tiene que refrescar las vistas

Comment: @diegoveloper. entonces es normal ese doble rebuild? como podria hacer para ejecutarlo solo 1 vez? Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: no hay problema si hay más de 1 rebuild, sobretodo considerando este del cambio de tema